# How to run my app with privileges for access to _every_ directory?

Tags: c#, .net, security, file-io, permissions

I am working on a small backup application for my personal use, and as part of it I would like to iterate through every directory on a given disk.

I have set my app to run with administrator privileges using the manifest and while methods like `GetDirectories()` can now enter system folders they still fail with an `UnauthorizedAccessException` when accessing `Documents and Settings`.

I will (have to) filter out system files/open files etc, of course, but for now just generating the list I want to give it access to the *entire* hard drive, but neither the 'requireAdministrator' or 'highestAvailable' requestedExecutionLevel appear to do that; how can I give it access to the entire drive?

Comment: Its not often you see a question on SO about making an app less secure.

Comment: @Rook, I can make the most secure backup program in the world so long as it doesn't acctually have to _back up_ any files. ;) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2009/09/29/i-can-make-it-arbitrarily-fast-if-i-don-t-actually-have-to-make-it-work.aspx

Comment: You missed my point.  An important principal of security is limiting the access of your application or administrators.  When you application is hacked then it maybe possible for the attacker obtain these rights.

Comment: @Rook, Ahh ok, I see what you mean; but how would I go about allowing my program access to 'Documents and Settings', without elevating the application itself? (Since essentially that is what this question is about. My thinking was that there was no way to get access to a personal directory without administrator rights, or those of the user to whom the directory belongs - now though it appears that even this isn't enough - which makes me think the approach is wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to have FileIOPermissionAccess.AllAccess permission. For that, you'll need to login as an administrator. If you cannot do that, your best change is to just skip the folders. Below sample is from a similar question:

```
try
{
    Directory.GetFiles(path)
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(s => files.Add(s));

    Directory.GetDirectories(path)
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(s => AddFiles(s, files));
}
catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
{
    // ok, so we are not allowed to dig into that directory. Move on.
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am an administrator and am running VS as an administrator, the manifest ensures that (though I get no UAC prompt for my app), yet I still recieve the security exception.
I saw a couple of similar questions but skipping the directory isn't an option - its a backup program, 'documents and settings' is the most important directory of all! ;)

Comment: @sebf, GetDirectories is designed specifically for that (to protect you from accidentally damage system files). Looking into the method implementation with reflector, I see that some of UnauthorizedAccessException is hardcoded for all permission levels so if you 'really' need to access all folders, you need to fall back to WinApi with P/Invoke.

Comment: Ahh I see; i'll use Win32 for the actual file and directory operations. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, sorry, but I just tried calling Win32s FindFirstFile (& co.) but it fails (invalid search handle returned) when encountering Documents and Settings. On the MSDN page it mentions that the user must have permissions to the path (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx) so it must be my application, even though it is being run as an administrator. :( :s

Comment: Hold on, my code was failing in two different ways 'access denied' != UnauthorizedAccessException. I shall use my Win32 code to perform the directory search. Thanks!